# Individual sites on an OpenVZ container

Tags: apache-http-server, openvz

How do I go about setting up a single container on OpenVZ that has it's own website with its own path to the public html directory.

For instance, container 1 would have website1.com with its own directory of files it references for the public html.

Then container 2 would have website2.com with its own directory of files.

I am quite new to virtualization and I am hoping to have my own low end box set up, but I am practising on a local virtual machine at the moment. I just want to be confident I can do what I imagine to do before I commit to buying a hosting plan.